# Why does game dev use C++ and why doesn't the rest of the industry?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, performance, comparison

Its a fact today that almost every AAA video game released for the PC, Xbox or PS3 is written entirely in C++. Some vendors say they can't move to C# because large codebases for the various engines they reuse internally are already built and tested in C++ (physics, rendering, etc). And performance-wise, its a generally accepted fact that [C++ code runs faster than C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/212856/Head-to-head-benchmark-Csharp-vs-NET).

To re-iterate : **Why does the professional game-dev industry in general use C++, and why don't we?** Is it because the general line-of-business application doesn't require the "best performance you can get" and trading reliability (memory leaks, OOBs, stack overflows) for performance "isn't important"? Or is it just because C++ is generally "harder to maintain" (templates, pointers, malloc, etc) than the same code written in C#?

Or is it because development in C++ is "more time consuming" than developing the same featureset in C#, so you can't implement as many features as you'd like to? But even today, many high-end game-dev kits such as [UDK](http://www.unrealengine.com/en/) and [CryENGINE](http://www.crytek.com/cryengine) are written entirely in C++ and their [featureset](http://www.unrealengine.com/features/) is among the best you can get on any platform. **So if C++ isn't "harder" or "limiting" or "buggier" for such companies then why is it used so little outside the game-dev or scientific/HPC industries?**

Comment: Why the downvote? I've added references to practically every point I made.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this isn't entirely on-topic for SO.

Comment: Always take performance tests with a grain of salt.

Comment: Then can't you move it onto a site where its ontopic?

Comment: programmers.stackexchange perhaps?

Comment: Maybe this is more suited on programmers

Comment: Migration to programmers.SE requires a mod to do.

Comment: Who's "we"? If you think that C++ is only used in "game-dev" or "scientific/HPC industries" then you need to search harder.

Comment: One of the biggest reasons is that Microsoft, Sony, and Nintendo only support C++ for console games.  Game Developers build tons of tools with C#, but it isn't practical for the games themselves.

Comment: I use C++ everyday for embedded systems.

Comment: You are wrong, C# is also used in the Game-Industry. Not in big engines but some small ones use it ( It's also not unlikly that tools are developed with C# ). However to keep the framerate high you have to optimize your rendering code and use techniques like occlussion culling and instanced drawing and of course multithreading.

I've some contacts to the game industry and as you said, there is a big codebase which needs to be converted, this is one of the most common reasons for not using C#. You have to write everything from scratch.

Comment: Cannot add it as answer, because the topic has been closed.

Comment: @RetiredNinja What is with XNA for the XBox?

Comment: C# is not suitable for low-level code such as rendering or game engines. Its benefits are almost not needed in this code while its performance and memory consumption is several times worse. I've got 5 times performance difference when I implemented ciphers in C++ and C#.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not primarily about the language, it's the platform.

In .Net you can't use SSE, your ability to use the GPU is limited; some lock-free multithreaded algorithms can only really be implemented as originally intended (versioned pointers) in native code (and if multithreading is important, an efficient lock-free structure can provide great speed improvements); memory management is automatic in .Net whereas in high-performance scenarios you can gain a great speed benefit by micro-managing memory (separate mini-heaps for different object types), and you can vector through memory - which also links back to SSE where frequently you will have multiple pointers vectoring through large buffers, feeding values into SSE operations.

To name just a few.

These things are things that Business apps typically don't concern themselves with because if performance is really crucial at this level then it's likely to be a server it's running on ~(desktop apps are unlikely - even in trading scenarios it's likely to be the server that needs to be real-time), and a business who needs that performance will just chuck a faster machine at it; or a blade centre.

In a retail game environment it has to work on lots of different configurations of hardware, and so it makes sense to try and squeeze every last drop of performance out of whatever hardware the user is running.

I guess that more answers why C++ is used to code most games, rather than why .Net is ubiquitous in business - the lack of need of such performance potential is a factor, of course, as is I think the shorter development life cycle (generally speaking).  However there are more factors.

In some ways, though, it's like comparing apples to cows.  You select the tech that best fits the problem.

Comment: Why limited GPU? What i'm not able to do on my GPU with C#?

Comment: well okay perhaps GPU coding is quite accessible... :-)

Comment: If you are using some API's like OpenGL/CUDA/etc you can do this all in C# too. :-)

Comment: Yep - although I think if I was doing it I'd go the native route - probably using C++/Cli as the bridge - because the tooling and documentation out there is much more geared towards a C++ environment.

Answer (score 5):

You always need to optimize the *bottleneck* of your application.

In a game, the speed of the engine is critical to the performance of the application. Hence, optimization makes sense there.

In a line-of-business application, which spends X ms waiting for the execution of a database query, and Y << X ms drawing the user interface and executing actual "business code", optimizing Y does *not* make sense. Since X is the critical factor here, it's the *database engines* that are usually written in C, C++ or some other "high performance" language.

Answer (score 4):

In short points: C or C++ gives you the posibility to work with many more details at a lower level so you can get performance and memory gains from where you can, and that is really required cause a game requires pretty high performance requirements for drawing and redrawing things continuosly.

However such details are not generally required in bussines line apps because first of all they dont do as many "operations" that require intensive work so that allows use for managed code even though that gives you certain penalties they are not very observable cause the physical workload is lower. So the point is use the right tool for the right job. You dont use a scooter to do agriculture and you dont need a tractor to deliver pizza.